# Why does grantAssumeRole do nothing when trying to add new trust relationship?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript

I’m trying to add the Amazon EventBridge Scheduler (`scheduler.amazonaws.com`) as a trusted service principal to my Lambda role's trust policy.

After running this:

```js
// allow scheduler.amazonaws.com to assume
this.lambdaFunction.role.grantAssumeRole(new ServicePrincipal('scheduler.amazonaws.com'));
```

My Lambda's trust policy stays unchanged:

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Am I misunderstanding how `grantAssumeRole` works?

This is how I'm creating my function

```
new Function(this, 'MyLambda', {
      functionName: this.lambdaFunctionName,
      description: `Timestamp: ${new Date().toISOString()} `,
      code: # code goes here
      vpc: props.lambdaVpc,
      vpcSubnets: {
        subnetType: SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED,
      },
      environment: {
        ...commonLambdaEnvironment,
      },
      securityGroups: [props.lambdaSecurityGroup],
      handler: 'handlers.schedule_handler',
      memorySize: 512,
      timeout: Duration.seconds(60),
      runtime: getPythonDefaultRuntime(),
      tracing: Tracing.ACTIVE,
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

**You need to use the [`assumeRolePolicy`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_iam.Role.html#assumerolepolicy) property to change the trust relationship policy that grants an IAM entity permission to assume the role.**

---

As per [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_iam.Role.html#grantwbrassumewbrroleidentity), this is what `grantAssumeRole` does:

> grantAssumeRole(identity): Grant permissions to the given principal to assume this role.

And while this is true to a large degree, they don't clarify the no-op behaviour when the `identity` is a service principal.

---

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/main/packages/aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam/lib/role.ts#L593), `grantAssumeRole` actually just grants the `sts:AssumeRole` permission to the principal:

```js
/**
 * Grant permissions to the given principal to assume this role.
 */
public grantAssumeRole(identity: IPrincipal) {
  return this.grant(identity, 'sts:AssumeRole');
}
```

When the principal is a service e.g. `new ServicePrincipal('scheduler.amazonaws.com')`, this method will **never work** as AWS services don’t need to be given permission to perform the generic `sts:AssumeRole` action. They're designed to assume the necessary role, as long as the trust policy of the role allows it.

If it helps, think of it as the service(s) being auto-granted the permission to do `sts:AssumeRole` in the background.

---

What you want is not granting the Amazon EventBridge Scheduler service principal (`scheduler.amazonaws.com`) permission to perform the generic `sts:AssumeRole` action (since the service already has that) but instead, granting it permission to assume the Lambda function role by adding it to the trust policy of the role.

Try this instead:

```js
this.lambdaFunction.role.assumeRolePolicy?.addStatements(
  new iam.PolicyStatement({
    effect: Effect.ALLOW,
    actions: ['sts:AssumeRole'],
    principals: [new ServicePrincipal('scheduler.amazonaws.com')]
  })
)
```

Comment: Hmm I'm getting this error ```Property 'assumeRolePolicy' does not exist on type 'IRole'.```

Comment: The role was defined during creation of the lambda function so I didn't specifically create it. I suppose that would be the default role?

Comment: How is this.LambdaFunction defined out of curiosity? Did you create the role using the CDK?

Comment: I've updated the question with the code that defines LambdaFunction

Comment: But did you originally create it using the CDK?

Comment: Yes originally created through cdk

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this for my role:

```
const myrole = new Role(this, "MyRole", {
  assumedBy: new AccountPrincipal(AccountA) as IPrincipal,
  roleName: "MyRole",
});


myrole.assumeRolePolicy?.addStatements(
  new PolicyStatement({
    effect: Effect.ALLOW,
    actions: ["sts:AssumeRole"],
    principals: [new AccountPrincipal(AccountB) as IPrincipal],
  }),
);
```